# Create Date input field that works with Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have two input regions that are type="date" and type="time" respectively. I have also noticed that the new html5 input types do not appear to be compatible with Firefox.

How would I go about creating a separate date and time field with appropriate dropdowns. Would this be best as a Jquery/Javascript solution? I am embarassingly lost on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`date` and `time`](http://caniuse.com/#search=input-date) input types are not supported in Firefox.

Here is an incomplete list of polyfills:

- [jQueryUI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)
- [html5widgets](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/07/27/creating-cross-browser-html5-forms-now-using-modernizr-webforms2-and-html5widgets-2/)
- [jonstipe/date-polyfill](https://github.com/jonstipe/date-polyfill)
- [jonstipe/time-polyfill](https://github.com/jonstipe/time-polyfill)